# What does a comma mean in a square root?

Tags: radicals

We have this problem in my Discrete Math class: "Give the set to which each of the following numbers belong" and one of the numbers is "sqrt 93," what does the comma mean? I guess it could be a typo, but I don't want to just assume that.

I can't post a picture, but it's just square root of 93 with a comma right after (it's a bulleted list and no other numbers have commas)

Comment: It's probably a typo.

Comment: Or maybe it's just a comma. Like, to, well, separate, um, thoughts. Does the end of every item in the list end with a comma, except the last?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Okay, I'm just going to go with that, thanks!

Comment: @arctictern its a bulleted list, so thats not it, but thanks any way

Comment: @StarSweeper I use commas this way in bulleted lists all the time. So do others. You didn't answer my question: does every item in the list end with a comma except the last?

Comment: @arctictern in the question I said that this is the only one with a comma :)

Comment: You said none of the other *numbers* have a comma.

Comment: @arctictern Its a bulleted list of numbers. I wish I could post a picture.